# Gorm Ping Db Shards

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I am looking to manage a map of DB shards in my application. When utilizing GORM what is the process to actively PING all of the shards to verify connection.

I am looking for something like :

```
import (
   "github.com.jinzhu/gorm"
   _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"

)

for _, shard := range shardMap {
   if err := shard.Ping() {
      //DO SOMETHING
   }
}
```

The issue is that shard.Ping() isnt a thing. I feel like im missing an import somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up the syntax for this is

```
shard.DB().Ping()
```